# Adding Favicon to Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I want to add favicon to a next.js(version 13.4.4) app. Adding it for chrome is done, but I cannot add favicons for smartphone app and safari.

Now, I put files about favicon in `app` directory.
And, I tried coding like this.

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import Head from "next/head";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Tokyo Bouldering Club",
  description:
    "東京ボルダリングクラブとは都内近郊でボルダリングを一緒に登るために定期的に集うコミュニテイです。",
  icons: [
    {
      rel: "icon",
      type: "image/png",
      sizes: "32x32",
      url: "/favicons/favicon-32x32.png",
    },
    {
      rel: "icon",
      type: "image/png",
      sizes: "16x16",
      url: "/favicons/favicon-16x16.png",
    },
    {
      rel: "apple-touch-icon",
      sizes: "180x180",
      url: "/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png",
    },
  ],
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="32x32"
          href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="16x16"
          href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png"
        />
      </Head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {" "}
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: I upload the app to Vercel